# separar números de una cadena

Tags: c++, arduino

Estoy separando los numeros que solamente son de 8 digitos y siempre seran asi, el codigo no funciona ni me dice ningun error

```
void setup() {
}
void loop() {
  mensaje_sms();
}

void mensaje_sms()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    String Texto = String(Serial.read());  // introduzo en el Monitor Serie:
// 77889966Hola Mundo        :Los numeros siempre seran de 8 digitos

    String numero = Texto.substring(0, 8);   // estoy separando el numero
    String mensaje = Texto.substring(8);    //  el mensaje

    SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
    delay(100);
    SIM900.print("AT+CMGS=\"591");
    SIM900.print(numero);
    SIM900.println("\"");
    delay(100);
    SIM900.println(mensaje);
    delay(100);
    SIM900.println((char)26);
    delay(100);
    SIM900.println();
    delay(5000);
    Serial.println("SMS sent successfully");

  }
}
```

Tengo este ejemplo de entradar lo realice en c# esta en consola

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string texto = Console.ReadLine();

    string numero;
    string mensaje;

    numero = texto.Substring(0, 8);     ///la cantidad de numeros siempre sera la misma
    mensaje = texto.Substring(8);

    Console.WriteLine("\n NUMERO: " + numero);
    Console.WriteLine(" MENSAJE: " + mensaje + "\n");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

resultado de esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa porque creo que en tu cadena tus numeros son desde la psoción 0 hasta la 8.

Comment: creo que???????

Comment: ¿No tienes ningún ejemplo de tus datos de entrada?

Answer (score 0):

`Serial.read()` lee exactamente un caracter de la entrada.

Si no hay un caracter que leer, devuelve -1.

`Serial.read()` **no** lee un string.